# How to get the second class name from element?

Tags: jquery, class

I'm trying to find out how to retrieve the second class name of a class attribute.

#### For example, having:

```
<div class="something fooBar"></div>
```

How can I get the second class named "fooBar" ?

<sup>I know you can add, remove, and check a specific class but I couldn't find documentation how to retrieve a second class into a variable.</sup>

Comment: @user why do you want to second class name , if you want to change some css propert's on second class still you can say $('.8')

Comment: @gov, I'm using a second class name because I'm retrieving a lot of data and can't use any more attributes.

Comment: @user can you explain it more clear , just i want to learn why do you need all the class names .... // may be i am missing something.

Comment: Remember that [neither a `class` nor an `id` may start with a numeric character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names/449000#449000).

Comment: @david but it can end with numeric value, yes?                          @gov, sure. It's for a voting script. I have vote UP and DOWN, UP and DOWN are the second classes, this way I can tell which button someone clicked on. As for the ID and NAME attributes, I use them for something else. Using a second class trims some excess HTML for me

Comment: A class **may** start with a number in HTML (in fact it may contain any HTML-valid non-whitespace character). The trick is that the CSS ‘identifier’ token is more limited, so if you wanted to refer to the class `8` in a stylesheet you would have to use a backslash-escape sequence.

Comment: @use468312, it certainly can, yep. @bobince, really? That seems contrary to years of reading about html, xhtml and css; though I can't find an authorative source for my previous assertion.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use `split` like this:

```
alert($('#divID').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
```

To get all classes, you can do this instead:

```
var classes = $('#divID').attr('class').split(' ');

for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
  alert(classes[i]);
}
```

**More Info:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: @matt , its really surprise for my how people come with solutions so fast and even complete typing the code also , people are simply brilliant in this stack overflow. I am not at at all getting stuck anywhere in my development after creating a login in stackoverflow , i gained so much knowledge in last 2 months.

Comment: I moved to UI development just few months back , I used to code a lot in backend and middle tier, This site made my UI work really easy. I would have joined earler , but no problem.

Answer (score 11):

```
// alerts "8"
alert($('<div class="something 8"></div>').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer too though yes i was 15 seconds before :)

Answer (score 11):

This is how you would do it by referencing a div ID

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  alert($('#yourDivID').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
});
```

The split function will allow you to split a string with the specified delimiter.  This will return an array of your separated values. In this case will return an array of classnames.

Reference for split an other string methods http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string4.shtml

You should look into the following jQuery Selectors and Functions for accessing classes

**Selectors**

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/   select a dom element with the specified class

http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/  select a dom element that has the specified selector

**Functions**

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/  method to add a class to a jQuery object

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/  method to remove a class to a jQuery object

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/  method to toggle a class to a jQuery object

http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/  method to check if a jQuery object has the specified class

http://api.jquery.com/attr/  method to retreive attributes of a jQuery object

Edited:  [Nice cheat sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903135323/http://labs.impulsestudios.ca/downloads/impulse_studios-jquery_cheat_sheet-1.0.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the references! +1

Comment: aah requires 15 reputation, sorry, will try again when acquired :)

Comment: @user468312...your welcome for the references.  here is a nice cheat sheet you can keep near your computer http://labs.impulsestudios.ca/downloads/impulse_studios-jquery_cheat_sheet-1.0.pdf

Answer (score 6):

as an alternative, it's always better practice to use the data-* html attributes to keep track of states, e.g $("div.example").data("active")

Comment: good advice, someone (even the coder some months later) cold switch the order of classes or add a new one, as it would make no difference in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the value of the class attribute and split it on space.

```
secondClass = element.className.split(' ')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct. If classes separated more than one space and you have get second class you get empty.
Example:

```
<div class="something   fooBar"></div>
var classes = $('div').attr('class').split(' ');
alert('classes: ' + classes + '; length: ' + classes.length );
// classes: something,,,fooBar; 4
```

I use the next code:

```
/*
 *   el  - element
 *   num - class number
 */
function getNumClass(el, num) {

  var classes = el.split(' ');
  var newclasses = [];
  var ret;

  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {

    ret = $.trim(classes[i]);
    if(ret.length > 0) {
      newclasses.length += 1;
      newclasses[newclasses.length-1] = ret;
    }
  }

  if (num > newclasses.length) return false;

  return newclasses[num - 1];
}
```

Comment: Even simpler: `var secondClass = $('div').attr('class').split( /\s+/ )[1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your spilt like

```
alert($('#divID').attr('class').split(' ')[1]);
```

Then you can do this

```
 var classes = $('#divID').attr('class').split(' ');

for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++){
  alert(classes[i]);
}
```

Source [javascript split string](http://www.tracedynamics.com/javascript-split-string-method)