# jQuery: Getting "secondary" class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to loop through some elements in a document. These elements are of type `<tr>` with class `.input-row`. Some of the elements can also have a secondary class (for example `.input-area`).

I use `$(".input-row").each()` to loop through the elements, but how can I determine if the `$(this)`-element has a "secondary" class and if so, get the name of this?

Comment: use split. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239947/jquery-get-second-class-name

Comment: If you need to *check* the class of an element you might be doing something wrong. Nowadays `class` is not meant to store data anymore - there is `data-whatever` for it (available via jQuery `.data('whatever')`). If you already need the class to apply formatting a check using `hasClass()` is absolutely fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".input-row").each(function(){
  $.each($(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/), function(i, v){
    if(v !== 'input-row'){
      alert(v);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The question asks "how can I determine if the $(this)-element has a "secondary" class and if so, get the name of this"... your example means you already know the name of the class

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of all classes using `attr`, and you could simply get rid of the the class you used to select the elements:

```
$(".input-row").each(function() {
    var allClasses = $(this).attr("class"),
        otherClasses = allClasses.replace("input-row", "");  
});
```

If the element has more than two classes, then you will be left with a list of the other classes. To separate them, you could `split` on the spaces.

Comment: `$(this).attr("class")` is equivalent to `this.className`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the classes on the element and then remove the one you know exists('input-row'), then you will be left with any other classes on that element.

```
$('.input-row').each(function() {
    var classes = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('input-row', ''));
    if (classes.length > 1) {
        alert(classes) // Names of all of the remaining classes
    }
}
```

If you want to get them individually, you can do classes.split(' ') to get an array.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a declarative approach. You know which classes there can be, so write cases for them:

```
$(".input-row.input-area").each( /* ... */ );
$(".input-row.input-field").each( /* ... */ );
```

If you for some reason *don't know* the class name, you can extract it along the lines of:

```
$(".input-row").each(function () {
  var myClasses = this.className.split(" ");
  $.each(myClasses, function (i, className) {
    if (className != 'input-row') {
      alert(className); 
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this to detect the number of classes:

```
var nc = $('#myId').attr('class').split(' ').length;
```

Then if `nc` is greater than 1:

```
$('#myID').attr('class').split(' ')[1]
```

should return the 'secondary' class

See **[a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQLFg/)**

Comment: And what if that element doesn't have a 2nd class?

Comment: That's why I was checking the number of classes beforehand, but you are right: maybe this needs a little clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for this

```
var otherClasses = $('.input-row').attr('class').split(' ');
otherClasses.splice($.inArray("input-row", otherClasses),1);
```

Simply doing this

```
var otherClasses = $('.input-row').attr('class').replace('input-row', '').split(' ');
```

Will give you an extra string in the array with an empty value in it, because of the space behind "input-row"