# Ruby/Selenium Access property of cells in a table that frequently changes

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, selenium, automation

I am trying to access a property of cells in a table.

```
<table id="m-103" class="m-row" cellspacing="0">
<a name="2"></a>
<table id="m-108" class="m-row " cellspacing="0">
<a name="3"></a>
<table id="m-191" class="m-row " cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="m-st">
    <td class="m-jk m-N">
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the xpath I have so far

```
 .//*[@class='m-row']/tbody/tr/td[@class='m-jk']
```

but it will only access the cells in the first table.

1. I am  interested in the m-N class value. Not every table has the m-N value. I'm only interested in the ones that do. Is there a way to only check tables that contain "m-N" or do I have to go through each one and check and if so how do I do that? I know now only how to go to specific paths so I have no clue how to iterate through each table.
2. How do I access the second class value "m-N"? Every css or xpath Iv'e used does not work, and again they are only for a predetermined table.

I saw an answer but the person was using jquery? Is this something I should learn and use as well? Can I if I'm using Ruby and Selenium?

[How to get the second class name from element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239947/how-to-get-the-second-class-name-from-element)

There are many more tables this is only 3 of them I'm showing for the example. Also the number of tables and cells changes frequently.

Comment: what are the values? you want let me know.. So that I can help you out.

Comment: `m-N` value for *id* are you checking or *class*?

Comment: Checking the background color still. The <td class="m-jk m-N"> has the background-color applied to it. I need to find and test that the cells containing m-N have truly changed color. I know now how to check the color changed (thank you) but I am having trouble locating these specific cells.

Comment: I added the xpath I have come up with so far. Though the answer does not have to be xpath.

Comment: there are two `td` as I can see `<td class="m-st">
    <td class="m-jk m-N">`. Which one you want to access? Edit your post with specific need,so that I can give you proper solution. Which part of the html you provided will be having dynamic values?

Comment: The html you have provided is heavily confusing.. give the needed part only.

Comment: I will keep in mind. I will be studying this weekend and will post better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the td elements which have a class attribute which contains `m-N` you can use the xpath function `contains()`.
Try this:

```
"//td[contains(@class, 'm-N')]"
```

This could get a little bit more complex if there also other classes which contains 'm-N' like 'm-Nx'. Than you have to do something like this:

```
"//td[contains(concat( ' ', @class, ' '), ' m-N ' )]"
```

Comment: This does access it! I guess I have to brush up on how to properly construct xpaths. I thought my situation was so different. I'm still curious, if I wanted to go through each element that contains 'm-N' what should I do?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to iterate with ruby  (what you seem to use) over the xpaht result.